# Difference between label and fuction in assembly - Intel syntax

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm currently learning assembly and I came across subroutines.
Now how do you know if something is a label or a subroutine since they are declared the same way ?

```
label:
subroutine:
```

The only thing I know is that you use call for subroutines and jmp for labels.

Comment: If it's your code, then you know because you're the one who made that decision. If it's someone else's code you'll have to read the documentation, comments, or the code itself to figure out what is what. Some people might use local or anonymous labels within functions, but that's optional and not something you can count on.

Comment: You can't.  Subroutines are denoted by labels.  The same labels you use for anything else.

Comment: Subroutines are labeled.  Data is labeled.  Control structures use labels.  Some labels are private to the file and others are exported for use by other files.

Comment: there is no such thing really as a subroutine in assembly language that is a higher level concept.  Yes some assembly languages have syntax to declare a label as a procedure or subroutine in order to make the job of exporting or linking or reading the code easier.  At the end of the day a label is an abstract for an address,  a subroutine is a high level concept which requires an address and is often coded using a label to make writing the code easier.

Comment: in assembly language the same label can be used as an address for a function call instruction (depends on the instruction set as to what that instruction is) as well as a branch destination, assembly provides that freedom.  so even if you were to see a call to a label that doesnt make that code a subroutine it could just be some code...

Comment: intel syntax does not define an assembly language, only the assembler defines the assembly language and the syntax for labels is one area where assemblers tend to differ.  What specific assembler and version are you using?

Comment: @old_timer I'm using nasm on a 64bit machine and i use the Intel syntax

Comment: intel syntax has nothing to do with labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subroutine is a conceptual thing — embodied by a sequence of instructions — that is meant to be called, accept parameters, do something, and potentially return a value to the caller.  A subroutine follows some calling convention, which is an agreement on how to pass parameters and return values, and how to share CPU registers between caller and callee.

A label merely names a single point in either code or data.  Labels are used to name the entry point of a subroutine, to name the beginning of some data, to name points in the code for construction of control flow constructs, like if-then-else, while-do..

In some assemblers, e.g. MASM, there is a special syntax you can use to identify subroutines, as different from ordinarly labels; however, this is not universal, and, many assemblers don't differentiate subroutines labels from other labels.

Labels that are exported for use by other files (e.g. via a global directive) are typically subroutines (subroutine entry points), but can also be data.

---

Here's an example of why we sometimes think of labels as identifying a point in code rather than a block of code or sequence of instructions.

```
...
if ( a0 == 0 ) { a1++; }
...
```

we might see this in assembly's if-goto-label style as this (in MIPS assembly):

```
    ...
    bnez $a0, skipThen
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
skipThen:
    ...
```

The above label identifies the point past the then-part of this if-then statement.  By branching there, we skip the then-part, and transfer the flow of control to the next statement, whatever that is (represented here by `...`).

Due to the if-goto-label style, assembly makes us create labels constantly.  Naming labels can be tedious, so sometimes it is easier to use simple labels, e.g. L1, L2, L3.  Some assemblers support this with numbered labels, e.g. $1, $2 (these labels cannot be exported, and with some assemblers, there are ways to even reuse these numbers within the same file without conflicting.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer I get it now :D

Comment: @Ajvar: note that local labels within functions often use special syntax so they don't end up in the symbol table of the object file.  Erik mentioned special names like `1:` that you reach with `1f` (forward) or `1b` (backward) in GAS syntax, or `.Lname` again in GAS.  NASM local labels start with a `.` like `.loop:` (and are sort of scoped to the previous non-dot label: https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9 by concatenating label names).  BTW, terminology: a label defines a symbol.

Answer (score 4):

I might be mistaken, but I believe that they are practically the same in this situation.

You can use `jmp` for a subroutine as well, if it is a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

The difference is that `call` allows the subroutine to return control to the caller with a `ret` if it wants.  `jmp` does not, only modifying the program counter without leaving any info on where it came from.

For example, these two codes are equivalent in their behavior:

```
 foo:
  call B
  call A
  ret
```

```
 foo:
  call B
  jmp A           ; optimized tailcall to A ~= call + ret
```

[`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) pushes a return address (the address after the call instruction) onto stack.  `ret` pops the stack into RIP/EIP/IP, returning to the caller (unless you messed up the stack).  So you can come back to it once the other code is finished, but `jmp` just goes to the other code.

A label that you `call` might choose *not* to return, for example it might exit the program, like the C `exit()` function, ignoring the return address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I find it strange that there is no specific syntax to differentiate function by just looking at the code, problem solved thank you :D